# How to append text to the parent window's textarea?

Tags: javascript, appendchild, window.opener

Simply i want to append some characters to the parent window's textarea.

```
str="some character" 

window.opener.document.getElementById('id1').value = str;
```

It changes the parent window's textarea's value to "some character"..But I want to **append** this text to textarea's value. like,

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('id1').value.append(str); // not working
```

But it is not working.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try
`window.opener.document.getElementById('id1').value += str;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below.

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('id1').value = 
window.opener.document.getElementById('id1').value + str;
```